# Task manager disk performance: MB/s or MiB/s?

Tags: windows, task-manager

Does the Windows Task Manager display the disk throughput numbers in MB/s (1000-based) or MiB/s (1024-based)?

[image: Task manager throughput]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small program to test that. The program read ten 1 GB files over a relatively slow USB 2.0 disk drive. The program measured the time using a [StopWatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0).

From these results I can conclude that Task Manager's disk performance view uses **MB/s (1000-based)**.